# CREATE VIEW of UNION of two tables, merging rows

Tags: android, sqlite, union

I have two tables that are almost identical, representing data from the server, and user-entered data. I would like to display a list to the user of the combined data from the two, merging any duplicates of the value of one text column. When a row is selected, I then need to be able to access data from child tables, so will need the primary key and which table the key is from.

Both tables have unique constraints on (fk_id, column_a).

Server Table:

```
_id | fk_id | column_a
----------------------
1   | 1     | val 1
2   | 1     | val 2
3   | 2     | val 3
```

User-Entered Table:

```
_id | uuid | fk_id | column_a
-----------------------------
1   | xxxx | 1     | val 1
2   | xxxx | 1     | val 4
3   | xxxx | 2     | val 5
```

The search results I need would then be:

```
_id | server_id | user_id | fk_id | column_a
--------------------------------------------
1   | 1         | 1       | 1     | val 1 
2   | 2         |         | 1     | val 2
3   | 3         |         | 2     | val 3
2   |           | 2       | 1     | val 4
3   |           | 3       | 2     | val 5
```

I do not actually care what is in the _id column of the result set, but I need _id, as I am using a CursorAdaptor in Android.

I was hoping to do this using a view like this:

```
CREATE VIEW all_values AS
SELECT 
    _id, _id AS server_id, 0 AS user_id, fk_id, column_a
FROM
    server_table
UNION SELECT 
    _id, 0 AS server_id, _id AS user_id, fk_id, column_a
FROM
    user_table
ORDER BY column_a;
```

Which I could query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM all_values WHERE fk_id = ?
```

Is this possible to do using a UNION? A UNION will not contain duplicates, and a UNION ALL will contain all values. Is there a way to merge duplicates, or will I need to do a join based on the value of column_a?

Comment: Yes, but you must have the same fields in both SELECTs (add `0 AS myMissingField` if it's an integer or `'' AS MyMissingField`, if it's a string - to any of the SELECTs partecipating in the UNION which miss some fields from the other table). And please remove the unnecessary string delimiters (**'**)

Comment: So, using a UNION will merge those two result rows?  I've edited the CREATE VIEW statement in the question to reflect this.

Comment: Yes, correct. `UNION` will merge excluding the eventual duplicates. `UNION ALL` will include those ones as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNION would remove duplicates, but rows that contain NULL values in only one subquery are not duplicates.

You have to do this the hard way:

First, this query gets all rows that did not change:

```
(SELECT _id, fk_id, column_a FROM server_table
 INTERSECT
 SELECT _id, fk_id, column_a FROM user_table)
```

These rows can be output directly:

```
SELECT _id, _id AS server_id, _id AS user_id, fk_id, column_a
FROM (SELECT _id, fk_id, column_a FROM server_table
      INTERSECT
      SELECT _id, fk_id, column_a FROM user_table);
```

The server-only rows are those rows from the server table that are not in the subquery:

```
SELECT _id, _id AS server_id, NULL AS user_id, fk_id, column_a
FROM server_table
WHERE _id NOT IN (SELECT _id FROM (SELECT _id, fk_id, column_a FROM server_table
                                   INTERSECT
                                   SELECT _id, fk_id, column_a FROM user_table));
```

The user-only rows are those rows from the user table that are not in the subquery:

```
SELECT _id, NULL AS server_id, _id AS user_id, fk_id, column_a
FROM user_table
WHERE _id NOT IN (SELECT _id FROM (SELECT _id, fk_id, column_a FROM server_table
                                   INTERSECT
                                   SELECT _id, fk_id, column_a FROM user_table));
```

Then just combine those three:

```
SELECT _id, _id AS server_id, _id AS user_id, fk_id, column_a
FROM (SELECT _id, fk_id, column_a FROM server_table
      INTERSECT
      SELECT _id, fk_id, column_a FROM user_table)
UNION ALL
SELECT _id, _id, NULL, fk_id, column_a
FROM server_table
WHERE _id NOT IN (SELECT _id FROM (SELECT _id, fk_id, column_a FROM server_table
                                   INTERSECT
                                   SELECT _id, fk_id, column_a FROM user_table))
UNION ALL
SELECT _id + 100000000, NULL, _id, fk_id, column_a
FROM user_table
WHERE _id NOT IN (SELECT _id FROM (SELECT _id, fk_id, column_a FROM server_table
                                   INTERSECT
                                   SELECT _id, fk_id, column_a FROM user_table));
```

(The `+ 100000000` or something like that is required to get `_id` values that are unique in the entire result.)

Comment: Just to be clear, as I abstracted my example a bit, and I want to make sure I didn't confuse things. User aren't changing data. They are adding either completely new entries, or new entries to a child table, in which case a new entry is added to this  user_table (with a duplicate value from the server_table). Would this work in that situation? It's been about a decade since I worked in SQL, so I'm getting a bit foggy wrapping my head around INTERSECTs and UNIONs.

Comment: This query detects all differences. I don't know where your duplicate in the server table comes from, but differences are differences, and identical rows are detected by INTERSECT.